Define constraint to prevent values outside the smalldatetime range from being inserted into a DataTable
I have a .CSV file with different values. I have loaded these values into a DataTable, which has the same structure as a table in SQL Server, with the difference that the table in SQL Server has smalldatetime columns and those of the DataTable are of type DateTime. The structure of the DataTable is created dynamically according to certain user requirements.
Once the data has been loaded into the DataTable, I perform a SqlBulkCopy to copy the data from the DataTable to the table in SQL Server, but the process aborts (DataTable SmallDateTime overflow) because some values that exist in the DataTable are not in the Smalldatetime range "1/1/ 1900 12:00:00 AM" to "6/6/2079 11:59:59 PM".
How can I avoid or define a restriction, so that “out-of-range” values are inserted into the DataTable before performing the SqlBulkCopy process? Or how can I copy the other rows except the ones that produce this error? I would like to put some restriction when inserting row on DataTable and not check in code that the value is in that range, row/column as the case may be.

You can use a Linq to filter the datatable : DataTable filterTable = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field("date") >= new DateTime("1/1/2024") && x.Field("date") < new DateTime("1/1/2025")).CopyToDataTable();

Thanks jdweng, The answer does not satisfy my initial requirements. The DataTable has several columns that correspond to the smalldatetime type in SQL. This DataTable structure is defined by the user (through a configuration file, for example), so at first I do not know the columns that I should check to define it in Linq. As it is inserted into the DataTable I must obtain a result if it was satisfactory to insert the entire row (either due to an exception or something similar), that is, if the values of each column of type smalldatetime satisfied the requirement of being in the proper range.

I think you have a bigger problem here: " This DataTable structure is defined by the user " yet you then insert data into a table that is not defined by the user. You will keep having these problems with your setup.

SqlBulkCopy doesn't provide a way of ignoring errors, and i don't understand why you're so reluctant to validate data which should be pretty easy to do dynamically (check all columns for small datetimes and loop through the rows, removing faulty), so i'm gonna assume you have an X & Y problem, where the actual problem isn't specified in your question. Voting on closing for that reason. On an unrelated note, my belief is that imports should be an all or nothing thing, importing partial data is often worse, so the bulk functionality is working as it should IMHO

You can get the Date columns using : List dateCol = dt.Columns.Cast().Where(x => x.DataType == typeof(DateTime)).ToList();

@Alex the structure of the table is defined by the user (according to a configuration file), and the fields (columns) are inserted into the DataTable depending on the corresponding field in the CSV file

@siggemannen the records (rows) with errors are later validated and re-entered into the corresponding table in SQL server
